# In database drop down list value doesn't store.It takes null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu

For dropdownlist i use ajax. I have 2 dropdownlist in that when i select department post generate automatically.

deprtment.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Post</option>');
$('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
var country = $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').val()
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:50384/update_add_staff.aspx/BindPosts",
data: "{'country':'" + country + "'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
var options;
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>'
}
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').html(options)
},
error: function(data) {
alert('Something Went Wrong')
}
});
});
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Post</option>');
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').change(function() {
var stateid = $('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').val()
//$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:50384/update_add_staff.aspx/BindPosts",
data: "{'state':'" + post_id + "'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
var j = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
var options;
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>'
}
$('#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID %>').html(options)
},
error: function(data) {
alert('Something Went Wrong')
}
});
})
})
</script>
```

and my deprtment.aspx.cs

```
private void Bindcategorydown()
        {
            String strQuery = "SELECT [dept_no],[department_name] FROM [first].[dbo].[dept_add]";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "department_name";
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "dept_no";
                    DropDownList1.DataBind();
                    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Department", "0"));
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string BindPosts(string country)
        {
            StringWriter builder = new StringWriter();
            String strQuery = "SELECT [post_id],[post_name] FROM [first].[dbo].[add_post] where group_id=@dept_no";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_no", country);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            builder.WriteLine("[");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                builder.WriteLine("{\"optionDisplay\":\"Select Post\",");
                builder.WriteLine("\"optionValue\":\"0\"},");
                for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    builder.WriteLine("{\"optionDisplay\":\"" + dt.Rows[i]["post_name"] + "\",");
                    builder.WriteLine("\"optionValue\":\"" + dt.Rows[i]["post_id"] + "\"},");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                builder.WriteLine("{\"optionDisplay\":\"Select Post\",");
                builder.WriteLine("\"optionValue\":\"0\"},");
            }
            string returnjson = builder.ToString().Substring(0, builder.ToString().Length - 3);
            returnjson = returnjson + "]";
            return returnjson.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        }
```

It shows data but when i want to update data and i use

**lblTest.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();**

Comment: Have you tried DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value ?

Comment: Yes but it gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Where is this written ? "lblTest.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();" if its on change, then the dropwon should postback on change (by default it does not)

Comment: On Update button i write this code
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString() );

Comment: I think because you are adding items using AJAX then the server does not know the state of the drop down, therefore, it does not know what items exist and which one is selected, why don't you consider using AJAX on the button too, and send the value of the selected item

Comment: But my first dropdown value insert into database ,second dropdown is depend on 1st dropdown so that why it doesnt give value..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding values to `DropDownList2` via client side and any selection in that control will not be availabelto server using `DropDownList2.SelectedValue`,as that depends on viewstate.

Correct way to get that value is by using - `Request.Form["DropDownList2"]` . As that thing is posted with this name to server, you can access that using above.

Comment: Thanks for replay but it take null value.. :(

Comment: Where are you setting this `lblTest.Text` ?

Comment: I write like this 
lblTest.Text = Request.Form ["DropDownList2"];
and after that 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", lblTest.Text);

Comment: This is what I suggested and I know that, If you look closely into the question, it asks `Where` implies, where inside code you are using, is it is `page_load` or any button submit ?

Comment: i write this on Button submit

Comment: You need to see,if that value is posted to server or not, Correct way to use that `Request.Form ["DropDownList2"].ToString()` or you can try this `Request["DropDownList2"].ToString()` .

Comment: I try that but it gives error"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."